# Calculating several regression analysis with specific columns in lapply

Tags: r, regression, lapply

This is my data:

```
df1<-read.table(text=" Time1    Time2   Time3   MNR1    MNR2    MNR3

36  36  43  5   4   5
40  41  51  4   6   4
38  36  50  7   8   3
35  51  43  8   3   2
52  55  57  3   2   4
",header=TRUE)
```

I want to have a loop using lapply ( preferably) to analyse Time1 with MNR1, Time2 with MNR2 and Time 3 with MRN3 using regression model and ....

I have tried the following function, but I failed to get the results:

```
R <- lapply(1:ncol(df1), function(x) lm(Time[,x] ~ MNR[,x]))
```

But it does not give me the results for each group. Can we do it using lapply?

Comment: You haven't defined `Time` or `MNR` and if you do the index goes from 1 to 3, not 1 to 6.  `Time <- df1[1:3]; MNR <- df1[4:6];  lapply(1:3, function(x) lm(Time[,x] ~ MNR[,x]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lapply(1:3, function(i) lm(as.formula(paste0('Time', i, ' ~ ', 'MNR', i)), data = df1))
```

Comment: While this is an accepted answer it is not really a good answer because it doesn't explain why it works.  Would you consider adding some text?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `Map` to paste the corresponding column names or create formula with `reformulate` by passing the 'Times' and 'MNR' column names separately in `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) lm(reformulate(y, x), data = df1),
        names(df1)[1:3], names(df1)[4:6])
```

Or with `paste`

```
Map(function(x, y) lm(paste(x, y, sep="~"), data = df1),
        names(df1)[1:3], names(df1)[4:6])
```

---

Or using `lapply`

```
lapply(paste(names(df1)[1:3], "~", names(df1)[4:6]), function(x) lm(x, data = df1))
```

---

Or with `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(names(df1)[1:3], names(df1)[4:6], ~ lm(reformulate(.y, .x), data = df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`reshape` to a 15x4 long form data.frame `long` having column names  No, Time, MNR and id. The No column contains values 1, 2 and 3 and the Time and MNR columns contain the respective data from the original data frame. The id column is not used. It is automatically generated by `reshape` and contains the row number that the data in that row of `long` came from.  This long data frame is not only useful in producing the result asked for in the question but can be usefully used in producing graphics as shown later below.

Then we use `lmList` in nlme (which comes with R, no need to install it) to perform the regressions all at once.  Depending on what you want you could set `pool = TRUE` to pool the errors (instead of `pool = FALSE`).  Note that `out[[1]]`, `out[[2]]` and `out[[3]]` are the 3 lm objects if you want them separately.

```
library(nlme)

v <- list(Time = 1:3, MNR = 4:6)
long <- reshape(df1, dir = "long", varying = v, v.names = names(v), timevar = "No")
out <- lmList(Time ~ MNR | No, long, pool = FALSE)
out
```

giving:

```
Call:
  Model: Time ~ MNR | No 
   Data: long 

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)        MNR
1    53.82558 -2.5232558
2    56.96552 -2.8620690
3    45.61538  0.8846154
```

### Graphics

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long, aes(MNR, Time)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  facet_wrap(~ No)
```

[image: screenshot]

or using classic graphics:

```
old.par <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(nm in names(out)) { 
  fm <- out[[nm]]
  fo <- formula(fm)
  plot(fo, long, type = "n", main = nm)
  points(fo, model.frame(fm))
  abline(fm)
}
par(old.par)
```

[image: screenshot]